# Cancelling the canonical module in tensor products

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, local-rings, cohen-macaulay

Let $R$ be Cohen-Macaulay local ring with the canonical module $\omega_R$ and let $M$ and $N$ be two finitely generated $R$-modules. Assume that
$$ \omega_R \otimes_R M=  \omega_R \otimes_R N $$
Can we conclude that $M \cong N$ ?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: i think this question is sufficiently advanced that it doesn't need an exposition of what the user has tried

Comment: What is the motivation for this question? And presumably you only want to consider the case when $R$ is not Gorenstein, where the result is trivially true?

Comment: @Zeek If the answer is yes, then one can generalize the result, for any semidualizing $R$-module over a Cohen-Macaulay local ring.

Comment: @MohammadBagheri but do you think the result is true? And where does the question come from? What property of the canonical module do you think relates to the tensor product?

Comment: @Zeek this is a part of another problem about semidualizing $R$-modules. As any semidualizing $R$-module is a generalization of the ring, maybe the result is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$. For any non-zero linear form $l$, we have,
$$R\stackrel{l}{\to} R\to M_l\to 0$$ modules and $M_l\cong M_m$ if and only if $l=am$ for some non-zero $a\in k$. (For definiteness, take $l=x, m=y$ and then $M_x\not\cong M_y$.)

Tensoring with $\omega_R$, we get an exact sequence,
$$\omega_R\stackrel{l}{\to}\omega_R\to \omega_R\otimes M_l\to 0.$$
Multiplication by $l$ is non-zero, since $\omega_R$ is faithful, and the image is contained in the socle, since $lx=ly=0$. But $\omega_R$ has one dimensional socle, so the image is precisely the socle. Thus, $\omega_R\otimes M_l=\omega_R/\operatorname{soc}\omega_R$ and thus they are isomorphic independent of $l$. This gives an example where your question has a negative answer.